# Delete content of folders with same name in different subdirectories

Tags: files-and-directories

I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 11.3.

I have many same named folders (suppose the name "data") in different subdirectories of a base directory (here "d:\dir").

How can I delete the content (containing only files) of all the folders named "data" without deleting themselves?

E.g. for three folders:

```
d:\dir\data
   filename1
   filename2
d:\dir\tmp1\data
   filename3
   filename4
d:\dir\tmp3\tmp2\data
   filename5
   filename6
   filename7
```

I would like to delete filename1 to filename7 whereby these names can be anything.

Comment: Does it work for you: `Select[FileNames["*/data/*", "d:\\dir", \[Infinity]],
  Not@*DirectoryQ]`?

Comment: @Kuba: Yes this lists all files in all subdirectories named "data". And now only `DeleteFile@` infront and it works. Please post it as an answer?